# 16.04 kernel automatically rebuilding?

Tags: kernel

Does the kernel rebuild with apt update?
Does the kernel rebuild with apt upgrade?
As you can see the oldest kernel was built in Feb. of 2018.
WHY is the kernel suddenly starting to rebuild as of Jan 20 2019?
It has rebuilt 7 times since January!

```
root@......:/boot# lr
total 405619
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  3879946 Feb 16  2018 System.map-4.13.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     2850 Feb 16  2018 retpoline-4.13.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   213220 Feb 16  2018 config-4.13.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1501359 Feb 16  2018 abi-4.13.0-36-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4048670 Jan 29 12:28 System.map-4.15.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217027 Jan 29 12:28 config-4.15.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8128088 Jan 30 03:08 vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4049376 Feb 12 13:25 System.map-4.15.0-46-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217004 Feb 12 13:25 config-4.15.0-46-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8125784 Feb 15 05:18 vmlinuz-4.15.0-46-generic
drwx------  2 root root    12288 Feb 23 13:17 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  7710912 Feb 23 13:22 vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 51527888 Feb 24 15:53 initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 54706058 Feb 24 15:53 initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4049889 Mar 15 11:40 System.map-4.15.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217004 Mar 15 11:40 config-4.15.0-47-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8130328 Mar 18 07:23 vmlinuz-4.15.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 54721855 Apr 10 06:41 initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 54720620 Apr 21 06:50 initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4052501 May  8 13:14 System.map-4.15.0-50-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217286 May  8 13:14 config-4.15.0-50-generic
-rw-------  1 pmak pmak  8141336 May 14 11:09 vmlinuz-4.15.0-50-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4050792 May 16 03:48 System.map-4.15.0-51-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217286 May 16 03:48 config-4.15.0-51-generic
-rw-------  1 pmak pmak  8137656 May 20 06:18 vmlinuz-4.15.0-51-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 pmak pmak 55683268 May 23 06:05 initrd.img-4.15.0-50-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4050825 Jun  6 06:27 System.map-4.15.0-52-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217286 Jun  6 06:27 config-4.15.0-52-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 pmak pmak 55685304 Jun  6 06:56 initrd.img-4.15.0-51-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 Jun  6 06:56 grub
-rw-------  1 pmak pmak  8141080 Jun 17 10:19 vmlinuz-4.15.0-52-generic
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root     4096 Jun 19 07:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 pmak pmak     3072 Jun 19 07:24 .
root@.....:/boot# cd grub
root@.....:/boot/grub# lr
total 2382
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     712 Feb 28  2018 gfxblacklist.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    1024 Feb 23 13:23 fonts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    1024 Feb 24 15:51 locale
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    8192 Feb 24 15:51 i386-pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2398585 Feb 24 15:51 unicode.pf2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    1024 Mar 31 22:33 grubenv
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   22612 Jun  6 06:56 grub.cfg
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    1024 Jun  6 06:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 pmak pmak    3072 Jun 19 07:24 ..
root@.....:/boot/grub#
```

Comment: Looks normal. Upgraded kernels appear frequently. Reboot into the newest, then run `sudo apt autoremove` to clean up some of those old kernels.

Comment: @user535733 I suggest posting that, or something like it, as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your output looks normal. Upgraded kernels appear frequently.

Usually, your system automatically removes older kernels, leaving three-or-so on your system. There are many possible reasons why this automatic removal may have stopped operating on your system.

Generally, the easy way to restore automatic removal of old kernels is to:

1. Reboot into the newest kernel.
2. After rebooting, run `sudo apt autoremove`